# Retry limit exceeded Could not initiate connection to the endpoint

Tags: publishing, sites-9.6

We are performing Disaster recovery (DR) plan on Dev environment, firstly we have performed on CD Server, its worked fine and able to view the websites with newly created vm's & Databases.

same process we are applying on CM server, we are able to view CME but publishing fails due to below error messages, we have updated New Database details on CM & Topology manger web.config files. are we missed in any other place. please help me. Thanks in advance.

> 2023-08-30 12:41:55,118 ERROR [Thread-2] RetryBlock - Retry limit
> exceeded.
> com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientSocketException: Could
> not initiate connection to the endpoint.
>
> 2023-08-30 12:41:55,118 ERROR [Thread-2] TransportService - Unexpected
> error occurred.
> com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Retry
> limit exceeded.

Comment: Have you verified that your new VMs have enabled communications between them? From error it looks like your Transport service cannot contact discovery/deployer service(s).
Open Topology Manager in CME and verify that you can list capabilities from CD environments. If that works then check logs on CD services.

Comment: Good catch Stefan, will validate and update my findings. Thanks